# Certification Failed: Assembly has a non-empty manifest resources table

Tags: uwp

I'm seeing a certification failure...

```
General metadata correctness

Error Found: The general metadata correctness test detected the following errors:

The assembly NotificationsVisualizerLibrary in file C:\Program Files\windowsapps\58300windowsnotifications.notificationsvisualizer_5.0.0.0_x64__8rkfj2ay7vd1w\NotificationsVisualizerLibrary.winmd has a non-empty manifest resources table. Every Windows Runtime assembly must have an empty manifest resources table.

Impact if not fixed: Microsoft store doesn't allow apps that don't pass Windows Runtime Metadata Validation.

How to fix: Please ensure that the compiler you are using to generate your Windows Runtime types is up to date with with the Windows Runtime specifications.
```

It seems to be complaining about a .winmd runtime library in my project (NotificationsVisualizerLibrary), not the main C# UWP project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason this was happening was because I added an **embedded resource** file to my WinMD project.

I discovered this by unzipping the compiled appx and then opening the .winmd file for the library which it was complaining about with Notepad, and then scrolling down till I saw the familiar text from my embedded resource file.

Removing the embedded resource fixed the problem.